# Mysql loop data from 2 table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table as below:

Table 1: `common_member`

```
+-----------+-----------+
| uid       | username  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | haha      |
| 2         | walao     |
| 3         | alamak    |
| 4         | hero      |
| 5         | theone    |
| 6         | nobody    |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Table 2: `labour_slog`

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| uid          | slaveid     | masterid     | bytime      |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1            | 2           | 3            | 123456      |
| 4            | 5           | 6            | 456789      |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I fetch the data as script below:

```
$queryLabourSlog = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('labour_slog')." ORDER BY id desc");
    while($rowLabourSlog = DB::fetch($queryLabourSlog)) {
        $user_list_slog[] = $rowLabourSlog;
    };
    array_multisort($idss, SORT_DESC, $user_list_slog);
```

In my html, I use

```
<!--{loop $user_list_slog $value}-->{$value[uid]} on {$value[bytime]} forced hire {$value[masterid]}'s employee {$value[slaveid]}.<!--{/loop}-->
```

The html will display:

```
1 on 123456 forced hire 3's employee 2.
4 on 456789 forced hire 6's employee 5.
```

How do I join the `Table 1`'s username data to get the loop display as below?

```
haha on 123456 forced hire alamak's employee walao.
hero on 456789 forced hire nobody's employee theone.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table_slog.*, u1.`name`, u2.`name` FROM `table_slog` LEFT JOIN `common_member` AS u1 ON `table_slog`.`uid`=u1.`uid` LEFT JOIN `common_member` AS u2 ON `table_slog`.`slaveid`=u2.`uid` LEFT JOIN `common_member` AS u3 ON `table_slog`.`masterid`=u3.uid ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```sql
SELECT `uid_main`.`username` AS `main_username`,
  `uid_main`.`uid` AS `main_uid`,
  `uid_master`.`username` AS `master_username`,
  `uid_master`.`uid` AS `master_uid`,
  `uid_slave`.`username` AS `slave_username`,
  `uid_slave`.`uid` AS `slave_uid`,
  `ls`.`bytime` AS `bytime`
FROM `labour_slog` AS `ls`
  LEFT JOIN `common_member` AS `uid_main` ON (`ls`.`uid` = `cm`.uid)
  LEFT JOIN `common_member` AS `uid_master` ON (`ls`.`master_id` = `cm`.uid)
  LEFT JOIN `common_member` AS `uid_master` ON (`ls`.`slave_id` = `cm`.uid)
ORDER BY `cm`.`uid` DESC
```